# Add GUI control to splash screen of linux

Tags: linux, startup, splash-screen

I want to add a button, textbox,... into splash screen when starting linux and handle the signal of these controls. So how can I do? Please give me some keywords for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Configure or enhance your *display manager* [LightDM](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/LightDM) (or perhaps your *window manager*)

Maybe you want also to enhance the [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) boot loader.

Comment: startup screen when initrd runs scripts. It means LightDM has not yet started.